# How to solve the problem that the Jenkins pipeline syntax on the remote server cannot git clone the project

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to deploy jenkins on a remote server, when I push the code to the repository, Jenkins builds automatically.
I have uploaded ssh to github and can connect using terminal.
`ssh -T git@github.com`
`Hi admin! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`
In jenkins, I use `Pipeline script from SCM` to monitor git push events.
Credentials I choose to use `SSH Username with private key`, and fill in the private key of the ubuntu remote server, but when I try to build,an error occurs.
The error message is as follows:

```
Started by user iyao
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress --prune -- origin +refs/heads/iyaomz:refs/remotes/origin/iyaomz" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2675)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2099)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:85)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:619)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitSCMFileSystem$BuilderImpl.build(GitSCMFileSystem.java:366)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem$Builder.build(SCMFileSystem.java:584)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:219)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:191)
    at jenkins.scm.api.SCMFileSystem.of(SCMFileSystem.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:118)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition.create(CpsScmFlowDefinition.java:70)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:311)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: The main thing worth mentioning here is that despite the `Started by user iyao` message, Jenkins will use whatever credentials *Jenkins* has, to clone and/or fetch from the repository. It will not use the credentials that `iyao` has. So see what *Jenkins* gets when *Jenkins* runs `ssh -T git@github.com`.

Comment: Jenkins will need to use an appropriate *public* key, and Jenkins will need to have access to the private key that corresponds to that public key so that when GitHub challenge Jenkins to prove that they are who they claim to be (by presenting whatever *public* key you have Jenkins present), Jenkins can decrypt text encrypted with that public key.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your credentials include the user Git:

[image: https://issues.jenkins.io/secure/attachment/24768/PrivateKeyConfiguration.png]

As noted in [JENKINS-20879](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-20879?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true), try with a passphrase-less private key (one which is not created encrypted).